# eclipse cdt juno c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having a problem with eclipse juno c++.

If I choose 'build on save', it keeps building over and over as though the files had changed.

Is that a bug that you encounter too, or is it just my configuration that is not proper ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your configuration,  I don't have this behavior, at least with the following Eclipse on Mac:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722